# How do you access an Amazon SNS post body with Express / Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-sns

I'm in the process of rebuilding a PHP app in Node.js on top of the [Express](http://expressjs.com/) framework.

One part of the application is a callback url that an [Amazon SNS notification](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) is posted to.

The POST body from SNS is currently read in the following way in PHP (which works):

```
$notification = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

In Express I have tried the following:

```
app.post('/notification/url', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

However, watching the console, this only logs the following when the post is made:

```
{}
```

So, to repeat the question: How do you access an Amazon SNS post body with Express / Node.js

Comment: As context: the reason why this (reasonable, naive) approach fails is that SNS HTTP sets. 
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html
(SNS doesn't really grok JSON)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Another approach would be to fix the **Content-Type** header.

Here is middleware code to do this:

```
exports.overrideContentType = function(){
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-amz-sns-message-type']) {
        req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';
    }
    next();
  };
}
```

This assumes there is a file called ***util.js*** located in the root project directory with:

```
util = require('./util');
```

in your ***app.js*** and invoked by including:

```
app.use(util.overrideContentType());
```

BEFORE

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

in the ***app.js*** file. This allows bodyParser() to parse the body properly...

Less intrusive and you can then access ***req.body*** normally.

Comment: This is a great answer, especially if you want to use the same app to process the notifications and subscription confirmations from  SNS.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html#SendMessageToHttp.prepare

Is there a reason AWS uses `text/plain` as the Content-Type? It was a real headache dealing with this. Glad there was a solution out there

Comment: Look at [this topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=69413) and draw your own conclusions. Watch out for the dates. Instead of trying to find alternatives to work around the problem, it would be better for AWS to fix it.

Comment: You can now have Amazon SNS set the right `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. To achieve that, modify the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute of your Amazon SNS subscription, setting the `headerContentType` property to `application/json`, or any other value supported. You can find all values supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy

Comment: @OtavioFerreira thank you, this is the easiest path forward.

Answer (score 5):

This is based on AlexGad's answer.Particularly this comment:

> The standard express parser will only handle application/json, application/x-www-form-encoded and multipart/form-data. I added some code above to place before your body parser.

```
app.post('/notification/url', function(req, res) {
    var bodyarr = []
    req.on('data', function(chunk){
      bodyarr.push(chunk);
    })  
    req.on('end', function(){
      console.log( bodyarr.join('') )
    })  
})
```

Comment: Technically correct, the higher voted post is the "cleaner" solution of the named problem. Let the well tested framework do the job...

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [AWS Node.js SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/) - it can access all AWS service endpoints.

```
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();

    // subscribe
    sns.subscribe({topic: "topic", Protocol: "https"}, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } else {
        console.log(data); // successful response - the body should be in the data
     }
   });


    // publish example
    sns.publish({topic: "topic", message: "my message"}, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } else {
        console.log(data); // successful response - the body should be in the data
     }
   });
```

**EDIT: The problem is that the standard  body parser does not handle plain/text which is what SNS sends as the content type.  Here is code to extract the raw body.  Place it before your body parser:**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var d= '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('d', function(chunk) { 
        d+= chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        req.rawBody = d;
        next();
    });
});
```

You can then use:

```
JSON.stringify(req.rawBody));
```

within your route to create a javascript object and operate on the SNS post appropriately.

You could also modify the body parser to handle text/plain but its not a great idea to modify middleware.  Just use the code above.

Comment: I think this may be a stage earlier. My application is already subscribed. SNS does post to it as I can see it in the console, but I can't access the body of the post.

Comment: Ah got it, sorry.  I understand now what you are doing.  I believe SNS sends the content as text/plain even though the text is in JSON format.  How have you setup your body parsers?  The standard express parser will only handle application/json, application/x-www-form-encoded and multipart/form-data.  I added some code above to place before your body parser.  It will give you a rawbody from your request which you can test to insure that you are getting data from SNS.  Log this and then you may have to write your own body parser.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. However it did point me in the right direction with req.on and chunking so thank you for the input. I've put my solution as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that supposing that you're using body-parser.

Just add the following lines to your app.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/plain' }));
```

This information can also be found in the body-parser official document:
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: +1 Adding both the options worked for my use case because I need json for sending mail and from AWS bounce back returns text/plain type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Amazon SNS sets the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain` by default. Now, there's a built-in solution in Amazon SNS, which just launched support for custom `Content-Type` headers for HTTP messages delivered from topics. Here's the launch post: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-sns-content-type-request-headers-http-s-notifications/

You'll have to modify the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute of your Amazon SNS subscription, setting the `headerContentType` property to `application/json`, or any other value supported. You can find all values supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy

```
{
    "healthyRetryPolicy": {
        "minDelayTarget": 1,
        "maxDelayTarget": 60,
        "numRetries": 50,
        "numNoDelayRetries": 3,
        "numMinDelayRetries": 2,
        "numMaxDelayRetries": 35,
        "backoffFunction": "exponential"
    },
    "throttlePolicy": {
        "maxReceivesPerSecond": 10
    },
    "requestPolicy": {
        "headerContentType": "application/json"
    }
}
```

You set the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute by calling either the `Subscribe` or the `SetSubscriptionAttributes` API action:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetSubscriptionAttributes.html

Alternatively, you can use AWS CloudFormation for setting this policy as well, using the `AWS::SNS::Subscription` resource.