# Amazon SNS confirmation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to handle some Amazon SES (simple email service) messages via SNS (Simple notification service) via http(s) to our server.

However, I can't get our domain confirmed. What is the right way to do this? I have tried the 'sns-validator' npm module but he says that the message is missing the required keys.

We are using Node.JS with express. What is the right way to parse the validation message?

```
validator.validate(req.headers, function (err, message) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        if (message['Type'] === 'SubscriptionConfirmation') {
            https.get(message['SubscribeURL'], function (res) {
            // You have confirmed your endpoint subscription 
            console.log("confirmed");
            });
        }
    });
```

Edit:
I have logged the `req` and I only see the amazon headers in `req.headers`

```
accept-encoding:"gzip,deflate"
content-length:"1517"
content-type:"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
host:"[nrgokurl].ngrok.io"
user-agent:"Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
x-amz-sns-message-id:"[id]"
x-amz-sns-message-type:"SubscriptionConfirmation"
x-amz-sns-topic-arn:"arn:[arn]:complaints"
x-forwarded-for:"54.240.197.14"
x-forwarded-proto:"https"
```

I do not have the data as subscribed on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html#SendMessageToHttp.prepare
where can I find that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that the default express bodyparser cleans the body of the request.
So I implemented the code from this answer, and I have data in my body!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22871339/4548006